# How do I adjust the content in a page to only take up screen width?

Tags: html, css, responsive, breakpoints

Using dev tools my content shrinks at lower bps. Everything from my header nav to footer is inside a container. Container is set to:

```
.container {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px solid green;
}
```

At 800px, I have a horizontal scroll and the content shrinks, adding space to the bottom of the footer. Using a media query, how could I fill the screen with the container? [screen at 788 bp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr4mM.png)

[image: Codepen of my code]

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for media queries:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .container {
    width: 100vw;
  }
}
```

Check out the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`width:100%` this will make the container div to take-up all of the viewport.

Comment: Thank you I think that was it

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is `width: 100%` and `max-width: 800px`.